# AndEngine configuration not working in Android Studio

Tags: andengine, android-studio

I recently tried adding AndEngine to a new Android Studio project. I cloned the AndEngine project from Git, I created a library module that connected to the AndEngine folder. After that, I added an AndEngine test program (pretty much empty) and I tried running it. I got a bunch of errors saying that the AndEngine resources did not exist (inside said test program). I based what I did on this guide https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fcSowvlKMqfTjM9r1mMP48KEhWbkJZGBDR5duFg4QYc/edit

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday I was trying to do the same thing. I never got anywhere because the document seems to be out of date with the new version of Android Studio.

Instead I opened the AndEngine project separately and built it to a jar and placed the jar in my original project's lib folder. Worked great for me after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Import Module" instead of creating a library module in new Android Studio (0.8.1). Works great